# Swift Regex capture filename between brackets?

Tags: swift, regex

I'm having an issue by capturing file name between brackets, The first file name captures successfully but the REST is not.

```
self.info = "<head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"{dailyChest.css}\"></head>"

           self.info =   "\(self.info)<center><div style=\"position: relative;background-image:url({toget.png}); background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position: center center;width: 100%; height: 600px\"><lottie-player src=\"{animate.json}\" style=\"width: 100%; margin : 0 auto\" autoplay></lottie-player><div class=\"reward\"><img class=\"rotate\" src=\"{vshinereward.png}\" style=\"position: absolute;width : 200%;top: -50%;left : -50%\" /><div class=\"rewardBit\">50,000<span>pts</span></div></div></div></center>";




        let regex   = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\{(.*?)\\}", options: [.allowCommentsAndWhitespace])
            regex.enumerateMatches(in:self.info.description, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (self.info.description as NSString).length))
            {
                (result, _, _) in

                var match = (self.info.description  as NSString).substring(with: result!.range)

                    match = match.replacingOccurrences(of: "{", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
                    match = match.replacingOccurrences(of: "}", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)

                if File_cache.isExists(filename: match)
                { print("filename \(match) exists")
                   self.info.description = self.info.description.replacingOccurrences(of: "{\(match)}", with: File_cache.get(filename: match).path, options: .literal, range: nil)
                }else{
                    print("filename \(match) not exists")
                }

            }
```

Any idea is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the pattern

```
"\\{([^\\}]+)\\}"
```

- Search for `\\{`
- Start Capturing `(`
- Search for one or more characters which are not closing brace `[^\\}]+`
- Stop Capturing `)`
- Search for `\\}`

And you are strongly discouraged from bridging Swift `String` to `NSString` for using `NSRange`, use always the dedicated API to convert `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>` and vice versa for example

```
let info = self.info.description
regex.enumerateMatches(in: info, range: NSRange(info.startIndex..., in: info)) { result, _, _ in
```

and

```
let range = Range(result!.range, in: info)!
var match = String(info[range])
```